# Need assistance tracking down 'index generation failed' error message when adding record to openldap

Tags: python, python-2.7, openldap, python-ldap

I have a python (2.7.4) script that I am using to add a very large number of groups to an OpenLDAP server using the ldap library.  For the vast majority of the groups I am able to add them with no issues.  For a subset of groups though, I am seeing the following in my logs:

```
    09-17 23:35|ERROR|13213|ldapcmd|add|{'info': 'index generation failed', 'desc': 'Internal (implementation specific) error'}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/export/home/somedir/lib/somedir/db/ldapcmd.py", line 308, in add
        self._RESULTS = self.__conn.add_s(dn, ldif)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 186, in add_s
        return self.result(msgid,all=1,timeout=self.timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 428, in result
        res_type,res_data,res_msgid = self.result2(msgid,all,timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 432, in result2
        res_type, res_data, res_msgid, srv_ctrls = self.result3(msgid,all,timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 438, in result3
        ldap_result = self._ldap_call(self._l.result3,msgid,all,timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 96, in _ldap_call
        result = func(*args,**kwargs)
    OTHER: {'info': 'index generation failed', 'desc': 'Internal (implementation specific) error'}
    09-17 23:35|ERROR|13213|googleGroupsToLdap|<module>|Internal Ldap - Add FAILED: somegroup@somehiddendomain.com
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "../bin/somescript", line 707, in <module>
        INTLDAP.add(dn=DN, attributes=LDAPENTRY)
      File "/export/home/somedir/lib/somedir/db/ldapcmd.py", line 313, in add
        raise DatabaseError(e)
    DatabaseError: OTHER({'info': 'index generation failed', 'desc': 'Internal (implementation specific) error'},)
```

Has anyone seen this error before - and more importantly - anyone know how to fix it??

If logging needs to be enabled on the ldap server, any idea what the appropriate log level would be?

------------ UPDATE 3:25PM -------------

I enabled logging and discovered that the error was due to the lock table running out of available locks.  To fix the problem, the following was added to the DB_CONFIG

```
    set_lk_max_objects 15000
    set_lk_max_lockers 5000
    set_lk_max_locks 15000
```

After adding the above, shutdown slapd (or you'll have some rather not-nice things happen...).. You'll need to recover the DB in order to push the new values into the environment.  To do that you'll run `sudo -u ldap /usr/sbin/slapd_db_recover -h <directory> -v`

It should finish fairly fast depending on how many log files you have to go through.  At that point restart slapd.

You can check whether the changes took by running the  `slapd_db_stat -c`  command.  You should see something like this (lotsa lines removed here...)---

```
    15000   Maximum number of locks possible
    5000    Maximum number of lockers possible
    15000   Maximum number of lock objects possible
```